# Equivalence of functionals $L^\infty \to \mathbf{R}$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a probability space and denote by $L^\infty$ be the set of equivalence classes of essentially bounded $\mu$-measurable functions $X\to \mathbf{R}$.

Let also $T: L^\infty \to \mathbf{R}$ and $T^\prime: L^\infty \to \mathbf{R}$ be two linear functionals such that: 
(i) $T(f)\ge 0$ and $T^\prime(f)\ge 0$ whenever $f\ge 0$ (with respect to the product order);
(ii) $T(f)\neq 0$ and $T^\prime(f)\neq 0$ whenever $f\ge 0$ and $f\neq 0$;
(iii) $T(f_n) \to T(f)$ and $T^\prime(f_n) \to T^\prime(f)$ whenever $f_n \to f$.

Is it true that $T$ and $T^\prime$ are equivalent, i.e., there exist $a,b>0$ such that
$$
\forall 0<f \in L^\infty, \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,aT^\prime(f) \le T(f) \le bT^\prime(f)\,\,?
$$

Comment: It seems that you have no assumptions whatsoever on $T'$. Is this intentional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(In general it's not true. Assume there exist $A, B\in \Sigma$ such that $0<\mu(A),\mu(B)<\infty$ and $A\cap B=\emptyset$. Then the functionals $T(f)=\int_A f d\mu$ and $T'(f)=\int_B f d\mu$ fulfill all your conditions except the desired inequality.)

Take $X=\mathbb{N}, \Sigma=2^{\mathbb{N}}, \mu(\{ n \})= 2^{-n}$. Define for $0<a<1$

$$ T_a (f)= \sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} a^n f(n).$$

Then $T_a$ is a bounded linear operator $T_a(f)\geq 0$ and $T_a(f)\neq 0$ for $f\geq 0$ and $f\neq 0$. However, for $f=\chi_{\{ n\}}$ we get

$$ T_a(f)= a^n $$

Hence, taking $T=T_{1/2}$ and $T'=T_{1/3}$ gives you a counterexample.

Comment: If $f=\chi_B$ (the indicator function of $B$), then $f>0$ (or better, its equivalence class), while $T(f)=0$..

Comment: For me $f>0$ means that $\mu(\{x\in X: f(x)\leq 0\})=0$. Which in your example is not the case. What do you mean by $f>0$?

Comment: $f>0$ is a standard notation for $f\ge 0$ and $f\neq 0$, which is weaker than what you wrote above

Comment: I see your point. Sorry, I never saw that definition.

Comment: I rewrote it in an equivalent way, avoiding the $>$ symbol ;) It is fine anyway (I *think* that the answer should be affirmative..)

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti Why do you think that it should be true?

Comment: Your example works fine. I was just trying to prove something false, well :)